# I've been asked to implement a Tree based Map, and have no idea what I'm doing

Tags: java, dictionary, tree

The assignment is as follows:

(50 points) Write a class called TreeMap, a generic class with 2 type variables, K and V (K is a key and V is a value that is retrievable through its key). The class should have the following methods:

**public V get(K key);**
This method should retrieve the value stored in the map under the specified key, or null if the key does not exist in the map.

**public V put(K key, V val);**
This method should store the specified value under the key. If the key already exists in the map, the previous value should be returned (and overwritten by the new value). If the key does not already exist, the method should return null.

**public Set<K> keySet();**
This method should return a Java Set containing all keys in the map, in the Key's natural ordering (for example, alphabetical order for Strings).

The get and put methods should operate in worst-case Θ(log n) time, and keySet in Θ(n) time. You should use the red-black tree code from lecture as a starting point for your code

---

I'm not just posting here anticipating someone to give me the answers, I just need help. I've searched all around the web and everything related to this question is either over my head/seems out of the scope of the assignment, or nonexistent.

How could get(), put(), and keySet() be the only required methods? How could a red-black tree possibly work without methods such as rotateRight(), rotateLeft(), etc.? Am I supposed to be doing everything those methods would do by just making the put() method huge?

You're going to laugh, but this is all I have so far and do not know where to continue.

```
import java.util.Set;

public class TreeMap301&lt;K, V&gt; {

    K key;
    V value;
    private int size = 0;

public V get(K key){
    return null;
}

public V put(K key, V val){

    size += 1;
    return null;
}

public Set&lt;K&gt; keySet(){
    return null;
}

public int size(){
    return size;
}
}
```

I'm not even sure how this should be implemented. Am I to just make a list for all keys and a list for all values? Seems like that would defeat the purpose. I'm just looking for some guidance. I know that I'm lost in this class so please don't tell me that.

Comment: Check source code of Java's `Treemap` on [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/TreeMap.java)

Comment: *"The class should have the following methods..."* does not mean the class **can only** have the following methods.

Comment: You're right, but that is generally what this professor means when he words it in such a way, I've been taking him for a year. His sample solutions to things like this are always 10x shorter than the actualy Java implementations, and it often confuses me. Also, I have looked at Java's source code. It uses things we haven't talked about yet, and I would certainly be asked to stay after class if I used most things from it.

Comment: I suspect "should have the following methods" really means "should have the following *public* methods". You will certainly need plenty of private methods to make this work.

Comment: What about this "red-black tree code from lecture"? If you've understood that, it should be more than 90% of the required work.

Comment: well that's what I'm confused about. The lecture code is literally 100% complete, so I'm not sure if I'm just supposed to copy it over. Does it mean that I should be calling the class from lecture, instead of recoding it?

Comment: Maybe you should email or talk to your professor or TA and ask.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looking for hints rather than having anyone do your assignment for you (and thanks for letting us know it is an assignment). Here are some ideas to get you started:

1. If you already have code for a red-black tree then you are a long way to a map already. Each node in your RB tree should hold a key and a value.
2. The get method is really just searching for a key in your tree and returning the value in the node you find. That should be trivial.
3. The put method is not much harder: it is adding a new node to the tree with the given key and value (with appropriate handling of the situation in which the key already exists). This is where all your rebalancing code is called from.
4. The keySet method is slightly more complex. It involves walking through every node in the tree and adding the key to a set which is then returned. Again not too challenging.

If you would like any specific help with any of these then please post your code attempting an implementation and I'm sure there'll be people who can offer help.

Comment: So I'm trying to get started and I am very frustrated with the way my professor does things. So I'm trying to write my program, extending the red-black tree code from lecture. Problem is, my class, the red-black class, and the test client class all need to be in a named package to be able to extend. But then, the problem is that the RedBlack class imports classes from the default package that can no longer be imported when I move the class to the named package, which must be done.

Secondly, my professors code is giving me errors, such as final Queue<T> q = new Queue<>; Queue is an interface..

Comment: I think you'll need to put your import issues into a separate question. I don't know what you mean by 'imports classes from the default package'. In general moving a class to a new package should not cause issues if you have the correct import statements.